# Weird system dialog keeps showing up on OSX

Tags: macos

For some time already I get a system dialog showing up in my computer (OSX El Capitan, 10.11.6), saying:

> accountsd wants to use your confidential information stored in "Skype for Desktop MSA" in your keychain. Do you want to allow access to this item?

It also offers three buttons:

- Always Allow
- Deny
- Allow

But no matter which one I click, the dialog keeps poping-up again and again, sometimes immediately, sometimes after a few seconds.

I've tried uninstalling Skype and removing any references to Skype and accountsd in my Keychain, without success. The annoying dialog always comes back. Any idea how to get rid of it?

Thanks

Comment: see https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201609

Comment: @DaniilManokhin thanks for the answer but when I try to edit the password (which, by the way, I haven't changed for a very long time), the spinning-wheel cursor shows up and the keychain app gets in "not responding" state. I have also notices that, in the keychain app, the lock icon  in the top-left corner is shown as unlocked. I f I click it to lock it, I also get the rainbow spinning wheel and the app becomes unresponsive. thanks!

Comment: I'd run etrecheck.com and post here.  Something is being loaded to cause this.  maybe etrecheck can spot it.